# Clear Notification on Android programmatically without remove Chat Bubbles

Tags: android, chat, android-11

I got a problem with Android Notification while developing my Messaging App.
My App need to clear notification on Status Bar, so I call [Notification#cancel(id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#cancel(int))
But this function also close the Chat Bubble relate to this Notification.
I tried hundreds way to clear Notification on Status Bar & keep Bubbles on Screen but can't
[image: Chat Bubbles relate to Notification][image: The Notification I want to clear programmatically]
Any one here face this problem and has the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cancelling the notification, you can republish it while calling [`setSuppressNotification(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BubbleMetadata.Builder#setSuppressNotification(boolean)) on it's bubble metadata & `setOnlyAlertOnce(true)` on its builder. It will keep the bubble and remove the notification along with the bubble badge and launcher shortcut badges, if any.

Beware that for this to work, your app must be visible on the screen.